# How to remove button after submit form using PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I need one help.I need to totally remove the submit button after submit the form and when it will be submitted the button will display to user.I am explaining my code below.

```
<form name="billdata" id="billdata"  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" onSubmit="javascript:return checkForm();" action="complain.php">
  <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
      <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px"> Name :</span>
       <input type="text" name="u_name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Add Name" onKeyPress="clearField('name');">
        </div> 
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="complainSubmit"  id="addProfileData" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

> complain.php:

```
require_once("./include/dbconfig.php");
if(isset($_REQUEST['complainSubmit']))
{
 // ......data is collecting here....
}
```

when data are submitted successfully the below part is executing.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   var phpVar = "<?php echo $_GET['success'];?>";
    //console.log('php',phpVar=='');
    if(phpVar == 1 && phpVar!=''){
        alert('Submitted successfully.');
        //var subButton=document.getElementById('addProfileData');
        //subButton.disabled=false;
    }
    else if(phpVar == 0 && phpVar!=''){
        alert('Unable to add.\\nTry again.');   
    }
    else{
        // nothing
    }
</script>


<script>
 function checkForm(){
    var s=document.billdata;
    if(s.u_name.value==''){
        alert('Please enter name');
        s.u_name.focus();
        s.u_name.style.borderColor = "red";
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Here i need to button hide when the data is going to submit and it will again display after the submit.Please help me.

Comment: Do you mean hide the button between the time the user clicks "submit" to the time the page reloads? Seems a bit of an odd request.

Comment: $(".Buttonclass").html("Processing please wait");

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont add a hide CSS-Selector or remove it by checking via if-statement?

CSS-Version:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success <?php ($isSubmitted ? ' hideme' : '')?>" name="complainSubmit"  id="addProfileData" value="Submit">
```

Except a new CSS-Selector: `.hideme { display:none }`

Via PHP/Template:

```
html...
<?php if(!$isSubmitted) : ?>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="complainSubmit"  id="addProfileData" value="Submit">
<?php endif; ?>
html...
```

Dont forget: You dont need close input html-tag: `<input/>` just `<input>`

And what is wrong to hide the button via JS?

```
document.getElementById("addProfileData").style.display = "none";
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Prompt hiding after clicking:

```
<button onclick="javascript:this.style.display='none'">
   Submit Button
</button>
```

in your example:

```
<input onclick="javascript:this.style.display='none'" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="complainSubmit"  id="addProfileData" value="Submit"/>
```

Comment: where i will add this `document.getElementById("addProfileData").style.display = "none";` its also checking the blank input field at each time of click.

Comment: for example in your JS-Check: 

if(phpVar == 1 && phpVar!=''){
        alert('Submitted successfully.');
        document.getElementById("addProfileData").style.display = "none";
    }

Comment: when submitted successfully the button should display.

Comment: okay that was not clear because you write: "I need to totally remove the submit button after submit the form"

then change "none" to "block" and set to the submit button "style="display: none""

Comment: here i need when data is going to submit it will display:none and after alert message it will again block.

Comment: okay i think i understand you right now. you dont want to be one then more click on the submit button?

check the last update please! this hiding the submit button directly after clicking. So you need nothing more via PHP or JS.

Comment: please check i have another click event inside the form it might affect there when blank input field is checking.

Comment: one thing: you want to hide the button directly after submitting?

in your "checkForm()" add a else-block with: "document.getElementById("addProfileData").style.display = "none";"

Comment: and this cant we work: var phpVar = "<?php echo $_GET['success'];?>";

add a hidden input field with name="success" or add this:

you have to change it to: var phpVar = "<?php $isSubmitted; ?>";

in your complain.php after checking $_REQUEST: "$isSubmitted = true"

Comment: let me to check as per you.

Answer (score 0):

A javascript code such as:

```
document.getElementById("your_div").innerHTML = "";
```

will erase the content of your div.

So, byt tagging the entire form, then erasing its contents, you can "hide" it.